# Why some events are missing in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, analytics, google-tag-manager

### Intro

In our e-commerce site, we are using Google Tag Manager to submit the data to Google Analytics. We have setup custom report for login using custom dimensions & metrics.

---

### Problem statement

We are submitting each event to GTM from our site. But in the GA custom report, some events are missing.

`Login Report`

[image]

Ideally `LoginSubmitCount = LoginFails + LoginSuccess`;

But here is the report at index

`1.` LoginSubmit is 6, where LoginFails is 7, which means 1 LoginSubmit event skipped
`7.` LoginSubmit is 2 but there is no event for fail or success

---

**Events**

```
SITE ACTION             EVENT TO GTM 

Click on login button   Login Submit
On login error          Login Fail
On login success        Login Success
```

**JSTL/JavaScript Code**

```
function trackLoginSubmit(userName) {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({
              'event': 'user-login-submit',
              'method': 'onsite',
              'user-id': userName
            });
}

<c:if test="${loginFail}">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
           'event': 'user-login-fail',
           'method': 'onsite',
           'user-id': ${userName},
           'validation-error':${loginFailMsg}
            });
</c:if>

<c:if test="${loginSucess}">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({
     'event': 'user-login-success',
     'method': 'onsite',
     'user-id': '${user.uid}'
    });
</c:if>
```

**GTM Triggers**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**GTM Tags**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**GA custom dimension**
[image]

**GA custom metrics**
[image]

Any ideas what can cause this particular problem?

Comment: When are the events fired? Before the user is about to be redirected (eg if success, before redirected to dashboard) or when user loads the result page (eg if success, when loading the dashboard page, if failure, when loading the error message page)

Comment: Refer events code in post  which is triggered and push  the data to dataLayer. I have tested this trough browser console & GTM debug addon. Event triggeres properly.

Comment: Code snippets don't tell me when they are actually executed (just conceptually: when login submit, if success, if failure...)

Comment: Ok.. onClick of login button trackLoginSubmit(userName) is triggered. loginFail & loginSucess event is written on global JSP, so I am sending loginSucess & loginFail flag from the server side on respective action, so it gets triggered. Do you want me to attach snap of triggered event here?

Comment: You wrote "Click on login button -  Login Submit". When user clicks on login button, he doesn't have `User ID` yet, no?

Comment: I am using username(textfield) value. The code only fire the event when it finds userID/username